# The syntax of the command is incorrect in Batch Script

Tags: windows, batch-file

So I have written a batch script to do certain actions based on the parameter (argument) input.
Here are the codes.

```
@ echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
title Sysmon Installation Script


SET ParameterEntered=%1
SET ConfigFile=%2

echo %ConfigFile%


echo Script starts: %date% %time%


:ParameterCheck
if "%1" equ "-t" (
    if "%2" equ ""  (
        echo -t has been entered.
        echo Version Check begins now.
        goto :EOF
    )
)
if [%1] equ [-r] (
    if [%2] neq [] (
        echo -r %2 has been entered.
        if exist %ConfigFile% (
            echo Force Reinstallation with config file %2 begins now.
        ) else (echo %ConfigFile% does not exist.)
        goto :EOF
    ) else (
        echo checkpoint2
        echo -r has been entered.
        echo Force Reinstallation begins now.
        goto :EOF
    )
)
echo Please enter a correct parameter.
goto :EOF
```

It works fine with "**test1.bat -t**", "**test1.bat -t abc**", "**test1.bat -r abc**".
However, it shows error of "**The syntax of the command is incorrect**" for "**test1.bat -r**".

Does anyone have any idea why?

Thank you in advance!

I have tried different syntax for the if-condition such as
"" instead of [], == instead of equ, etc.

Comment: To elaborate on VLL's close vote message, try `if exist "%ConfigFile%" (` instead of `if exist %ConfigFile% (`.

Comment: As all of the comments contribute to the improvement of the script, answer from @SomethingDark pinpoints my issue and it fixes it straight away. Thank you! (How do I mark it as an answer?)